# How to set the tflite model input tensor and output tensor on android?

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a model with:

```
input shape: (batch_size, 3, 48, 64, 18)
output shape: (batch_size, 512)
```

I want to convert this model to tflite model, and run it on android.

The official example of tflite shows that the input tensor is an `one-dimensional ByteBuffer`, and the output tensor is a float array.

How to store the input data with shape(batch_size, 3, 48, 64, 18) to the ByteBuffer?

In my project, I set `batch_size = 3` because the shape of original input data is (54, 48, 64, 18), and I use `numpy.reshape` to reshape the data into (3, 3, 48, 64, 18).

Does it really need to do the reshape first?

Can I store the data with shape (54, 48, 64, 18) to the ByteBuffer directly?

Comment: According to tflite [inference doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#supported_data_types_in_java), using ByteBuffer needs explicit given shape and dtype because the data in ByteBuffer is serialized. So anyway, why not use shaped arrays as inputs directly?

Comment: @zongfan so I can just use a float array([batch_size][3][48][64][18]) as the input tensor?

Comment: Python API has such an example to use numpy array as input. See this document: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python